# how to add tickercode to every single date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a beginner and trying to add a ticker code to each line of a data frame, I think I've found the place, but I have no idea how to do it, can anyone help?

```
# save__tickers()

def get_data_from_yahoo(reload=False):

if reload:
    tickers = save_dji_tickers()
else:
    with open("dji_tickers.pickle", "rb") as f:
        tickers = pickle.load(f)
if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
    os.makedirs('stock_dfs')
start = dt.datetime(2019, 11, 1)
end = dt.datetime.now()
for ticker in tickers:
    print(ticker)
    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
        df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)
        # Add tickercode to every single line (date) in df, I assume it's here
        df = df
        df.reset_index(inplace=True)
        df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
        df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
    else:
        print("")
        print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself, there was a command that could add a column to a csv file and set it to a value. The code now looks like the following

## save__tickers()

def get_data_from_yahoo(reload=False):

```
if reload:
    tickers = save_dji_tickers()

else:
    with open("dji_tickers.pickle", "rb") as f:
        tickers = pickle.load(f)

if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
    os.makedirs('stock_dfs')
start = dt.datetime(2019, 12, 1)
end = dt.datetime.now()
for ticker in tickers:
    print(ticker)
    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
        df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)
        df['ticker'] = ticker  # add filename as column to csv
        df.reset_index(inplace=True)
        df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
        df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
    else:
        print("")
        print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))e was a command that could add a column to a csv file and set it to a value. The code now looks like the following:

enter code here
```